# Get the key of a hash by knowing only one item inside the value which is an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, logic

I want to be able to get the key called "needed key" as a string out of this considering I just the value of "known_value

```
hash = {
  "needed key" => {
    :key1 => ["know_value", "unknown_value"], 
    :key2 => ["stuff", "more_stuff"]
  }
  "otherhash" => {
    :key1 => ["unknow_value", "unknown_value"], 
    :key2 => []
  }
}
```

In short how would I be able to retreive "needed key" from this code if I only know "know_value". So by simply using "know_value" out of this I need to get "needed key".

Thank you very much for your help.

Hopefully I am clear enough, otherwise please ask me to be clearer.

Comment: Presumably, `hash` is an example. Do you know, for example, that the values of `hash`'s keys are hashes whose values are arrays, or might there be more layers of nested hashes and arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to extract the desired key that is efficient in the sense that it avoids the construction of temporary, intermediate arrays, such as `hash.keys`, `flatten`, `hash[key]`, and so on.

```
target = "known_value"
hash.each_key.find { |k| hash[k].each_value { |a| a.include?(target) } }
  #=> "needed key"
```

This assumes, of course, that we are looking for any key that satisfies the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```
hash.select{|k, v| v.values.flatten.include?('known_value')}.keys
```

Comment: You need `.first` or `[0]` on the end.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Since I don't know whether the author needs all keys or just one key, I'd rather leave this choice to himself.

Comment: Good point. You might want to state that you are obtaining all keys that satisfy the requirement, as the OP was not clear about that. Your comment prompted me to state the assumption I made in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about one of them then you could use `find`:

```
hash.find { |k, h| h.values.flatten.include?('know_value') }.first
```

or if you want to avoid `flatten`, you could use `any?` on the inner arrays:

```
hash.find { |k,h| h.values.any? { |a| a.include?('know_value') } }.first
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a Ruby expert but I think this gets the job done.

```
hash.keys.select{ |key|
  subhash = hash[key]
  subhash.keys.any? { |subkey|
    subhash[subkey].include? 'known_value'
  }
}.first
```